# execute javascript as coldfusion page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I have a ColdFusion page that on it, has several `cfinclude` template calls which include separate files into the page.  I would like to update a javascript variable before each `cfinclude` template call.  I've tried using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
myvariable = 'new status';
</script>
```

However, the javascript doesn't get executed until every single template included on the page finishes processing, instead of before each one executes.

Is there some way I can actually execute javascript code AS the page loads?

Comment: Javascript won't run until after the entire document has been downloaded and is ready. You can use server-side technology such as cf to dynamically set the value of the js variable (as it is rendered to the browser), but the entire document must be downloaded before the js will be executed client-side.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling, not true, you can enable progressive downloading with cfflush; see my answer.

Comment: @DigitalChris Never heard of that.. good to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can accomplish this with [`<cfflush>`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_f_12.html).

CFFlush will send the current HTML/javascript output to the browser as it continues to process. It would look something like this:

```
<CFInclude template="process1.cfm">
<CFoutput>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    myvariable = 'new status';
    </script>
</CFoutput>
<cfflush>
<CFInclude template="process2.cfm">
```

... and repeat.

The javascript will be interpreted by the browser as soon as it is loaded. This sometimes causes unpredictable behavior since the DOM is not complete and in a ready state, but for simple operations it works.

Edit: note that you often have to pad your output with something like `<cfoutput>#repeatString(" ", 250)#</cfoutput>` before the browser will process it. See http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2006/11/29/A-Loading-page-with-CFFLUSH-and-JavaScript

Comment: Upon trying, this looks to be the way to go.  Going to make it work one way or another.  Thanks Digital Chris for your input!!!

Comment: Flushing is a great technique to incrementally deliver the page, but do be aware of the limitations it imposes. The first time you flush the response, the header is sent, meaning that you can no longer use features which generate headers, such as setting cookies or cache expiration headers.

Comment: @barnyr absolutely. This includes things that some devs don't realize are actually header modifiers, like `<CFLocation>`.